# How does GAE datastore index null values

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I'm concerned about read performance, I want to know if putting an indexed field value as `null` is faster than giving it a value.

I have lots of items with a status field. The `status` can be, `"pending"`, `"invalid"`, `"banned"`, etc...

my typical request is to find the `status` "ok" (or null). Since null fields are not saved to datastore, it is already a win to avoid to have a "useless" default value I can replace with null. So I already have less disk space use.

But I was wondering, since datastore is noSql, it doesn't know about the data structure and it doesn't know there is a missing column `status`. So how does it do the `status = null` request check?

Does it have to check all columns of each row trying to find my column? or is there some smarter mechanism?

For example, index (null=Entity,key) when we pass a column explicitly saying it is null (if this is the case, does Objectify respect that and keep the field in the list when passing it to the native API if it's null?)

And mainly, which request is more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The low level API (and Objectify) stores and indexes nulls if you specify that a field/property should be indexed. For Objectify, you can specify @Ignore(IfNull.class) or @Unindex(IfNull.class) if you want to alter this behavior. You are probably confusing this with documentation for other data access APIs.

Since GAE only allows you to query for indexed fields, your question is really: Is it better to index nulls and query for them, or to query for everything and filter out non-null values?

This is purely a question of sparsity. If the overwhelming majority of your records contain null values, then you're probably better off querying for everything and filtering out the ones you don't want manually. A handful of extra entity reads are probably cheaper than updating and storing an extra index. On the other hand, if null records are a small percentage of your data, then you will certainly want the index.

This indexing dilema is not unique to GAE. All databases present this question with respect to low-cardinality fields; it's just that they'll do the table scan (testing and skipping rows) for you.

If you really want to fine-tune this behavior, read Objectify's documentation on Partial Indexes.

Comment: Thanks stickfigure, I didn't think about the alternative of reading and throwing unneeded entries (kind of pitty, but still less costly than writing to the index 2 additional entries for a very common case). At the end, I end up checking if there is a column of a given name (to show the row only if there is no column), this has maybe a cost, but it's an alternative to study

Answer (score 1):

null is also treated as a value in datastore and there will be entries for null values in indexes. [Datastore doc says](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes#Java_Index_definition_and_structure), "Datastore distinguishes between an entity that does not possess a property and one that possesses the property with a null value"

Datastore will never check all columns or all records. If you have this property indexed, it will get records from the index only If not indexed, you cannot query by that property.

In terms of query performance, it should be the same, but you can always profile and check.

Comment: Thanks Ashish, sorry I was kind of lazy to read the docs it seams :) (I should have done it before writing the question). This said, I still don't have my answer about performance.

I will vote for Stickfigure's answer since he proposed me a real alternative by avoiding to write useless indexes (which is partially a performance answer)